# Is it possible to exclude functions/name-spaces from :reload on the Repl?

Tags: clojure

I have two functions which do IO in a dosync. Therefore when I do a

```
(require 'my.namespace :reload)
```

I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: I/O in transaction, compiling:
```

Is there a way to exclude the reloading of these two functions, or a whole namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have top level forms that have side effects (such as reading or writing things) you can protect them from being reloaded with the `defonce` macro:

```
(defonce launcher (fire-the-missiles))
```

This way if launcher is already defined, the form that defines it won't be re-evaluated. It's something of a code smell to have too many side effects in top level forms because when you do want to reload them it's more difficult.

Comment: thanks Arthur, out of interest where is best to put 'side effect' code then?

Comment: It's mostly personal opinion, though I tend to keep it in functions, so that none of the side effects happen until the function is run. Because I use clj-refactor constantly, it reloads namespaces whenever it feels like it, so having side effects at load time gets complicated.